# Running unit tests for SwiftUI App fails with macOS shared app template

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode12

I created a SwiftUI App (shared app between macOS and iOS template) using the default tests. The app itself is building without any problems but when I try to run a test, Xcode gives me a lot of error like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "nominal type descriptor for AppTest.Customer", referenced from:
      _symbolic _____Sg 10AppTest6CustomerC in CustomerTests.o
```

I wrote "a lot" because I have this error for almost all my models\protocols used by object declared in tests.

I tried to create a dummy project only for iOS and problem disappears so I think is related to macOS shared app template.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm encountering the same thing.

Comment: @EricGroom unfortunately, not yet...maybe XCode 13 (beta at this time) fixes this issue but I haven't tried